# задача на матрицу смежности

Tags: python, матрицы

> Входные данные
> Во входном файле записано число

> (1 ≤  ≤ 50000) - количество вершин в графе. В следующих

> строках записан граф в виде списков смежности: в i-ой строке, в порядке возрастания, записаны номера вершин, в которые идут ребра из 
> i
> -ой вершины. Нумерация начинается с единицы. Гарантируется, что ребер в графе не более 50000.

> Выходные данные
> Выведите развернутый граф в том же формате, что и исходный.

Пример:

входные данные

```
4
2 3
3

2
```

выходные данные:

```
4

1 4
1 2
```

---

Я написал следующий код:

```
n = int(input())
pairs = [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)]
lst = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for el in pairs[i]:
        lst[el - 1][i] = 1
pairs = [[] for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if lst[i][j] == 1:
            pairs[i].append(j + 1)
print(n)
for rows in pairs:
    for el in rows:
        print(el, end=' ')
    print()
```

Если вам будет удобнее, то вот ссылка на задачу: https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=359&chapterid=111539#1
Код выше проходит только 9 тестов:
Ошибка во время выполнения программы - вот что пишут в протоколе на 7, 8, 9, 13 тестах.
Если вы найдете ошибку в моем коде или же напишите что-то свое, что проходит все тесты, то я буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = int(input())
pairs = [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)]
lst = [[] * n for _ in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for el in pairs[i]:
        lst[el - 1].append(i + 1)
print(n)
for rows in lst:
    rows.sort()
    print(*rows)
```

Comment: старайтесь сопровождать свой код описанием того что и как он делает, чтобы новичкам тоже было понятно. Спасибо!